# Unable to perform an operation on node rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Trying to set up a rabbitmq with rabbit@localhost, but:

```
c:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.18\sbin>rabbitmqctl status
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@localhost'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.
```

Erlang + Rabbitmq + Win7.
I've started Rabbitmq service, it works, but nodes are created automatically with random names

```
attempted to contact: [rabbit@localhost]

rabbit@localhost:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on localhost
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on localhost
  * suggestion: start the node

Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-10012-rabbit@localhost'
 * effective user's home directory: C:\Users\andrey
 * Erlang cookie hash: LdQNaRpK/HR5vh8yRc6A2w==
```

Comment: The random name is for the `rabbitmqctl` process. ` node 'rabbit' not running at all` means that RabbitMQ is not actually running. I suggest checking the log files.

Comment: @LukeBakken, thank you! Indeed, rabbirmq-service notified, that process get started, but in fact it didn't. So problem was in rabbitmq.conf and rabbitmq-env.conf was different, after unifiyng them - everything works :)

Answer (score 1):

Next steps solved my problem:

0)add `set RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost` in rabbitmq-env.bat

1)rabbitmq.conf and rabbitmq-env.conf was different. But shoud be the same:

```
CONFIG_FILE=C:\Users\<youruser>\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq
NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
```

Comment: "rabbitmq.conf and rabbitmq-env.conf was different. But shoud be the same:" - NO. These two files serve completely different purposes [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html). In addition, on Windows, the latter file is named `rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` **not** `rabbitmq-env.conf`. More than likely this issue has to do with how your hostname is configured. `localhost` is a _very unusual_ hostname for a Windows system.

Comment: Yes, there are three different files: `rabbitmq-env-conf.bat` in `Program files` and `rabbitmq-env.conf` and `rabbitmq.conf` in `AppData`, and after I made both vonf files the same it started to work, and I really don't know why.